# Is my if statement ignoring my conditions?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom

I'm working on a calculator app and I have given each button a value corresponding to their numbers or characters.

I have an if condition that's supposed to check if the user clicks any button other than "C" or "del" (delete) button. If they do click the "C" or "del" button, no value is added to neither the userInput nor the display.

The problem I'm having is that even when I click "C" and "del", the if statement would still execute.

```
let userInput = '';
const display = document.querySelector('.display');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]');


for (let button of buttons) {

    const value = button.value;

    if (value !== "C" || value !== "del"){
        button.addEventListener("click", function(){
            userInput+=value;
            display.innerHTML += value;
            console.log(button.value);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have `value = "C`, then it's not `"del"`, thus the condition is `true`. When you have `value = "del`, then it's not `"C"`, thus the condition is `true`.  The program does exactly what you told it to, not what you mean.

Comment: `!(value === "C" || value === "del")` = `value !== "C" && value !== "del"`

Comment: just `console.log(value);`  and check your value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **AND** operator, because it should not be 'C' and 'del'

```
value != "C" && value != "del"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND) operator, because both condition have to be true.

```
value !== "C" && value !== "del"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think people have made it pretty clear already that the way you've made your if-statement, it will ALWAYS come out as true, because it will always either be true that it's not 'C', OR it's not 'del'.

However, I thought I'd add another approach: using an array, and using the `array.includes` function

```
const badValues = ['C', 'del'];
if (badValues.includes(value)) {
   // value is either C or del
} else {
   // value is not C or del
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to see what's happening if we write out the boolean truth table here:

```
+----------+------------------+--------------------+--------+
|  value   | value != "C" (A) | value != "del" (B) | A || B |
+----------+------------------+--------------------+--------+
| "C"      | false            | true               | true   |
| "del"    | true             | false              | true   |
| "banana" | true             | true               | true   |
+----------+------------------+--------------------+--------+
```

The only way for this to be `false` is if both the A and B condition are `false`, however that will require `value` to be both `"C"` *and* `"del"` at the same time. Which is not possible for strings. Thus, because logical OR is used, the output will always be `true` regardless of input.

Instead, using logical AND is what you actually want to accomplish:

```
+----------+------------------+--------------------+--------+
|  value   | value != "C" (A) | value != "del" (B) | A && B |
+----------+------------------+--------------------+--------+
| "C"      | false            | true               | false  |
| "del"    | true             | false              | false  |
| "banana" | true             | true               | true   |
+----------+------------------+--------------------+--------+
```